# How to read any of the file type using php7?

Tags: php, php-7, data-extraction, php-7.1

I have tried to extract the user email addresses from my server. But the problem is maximum files are `.txt` but some are `CSV` files with txt extension. When I am trying to read and extract, I could not able to read the CSV files which with TXT extension. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('2.txt', "r");
while(!feof($handle)) {
        $string = fgets($handle);
   $pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/i';
   preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
   foreach($matches[0] as $match)
{
echo $match;
echo '<br><br>';
}
}
?>
```

I have tried to use this code for that. The program is reading the complete file which are CSV, and line by line which are Text file. There are thousands of file and hence it is difficult to identify.

Kindly, suggest me what I should do to resolve my problem? Is there any solution which can read any format, then it will be awesome.

Comment: Still didn't get what is the problem? With `fgets` you can read any file line-by-line

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Any file but what if the file extension get changed. I have a `CSV` file in the midst of `TXT` files. But the file extension of the CSV file is `.TXT`. the program is not able to read the file and hence not able to process it. So is there a way through which any file can be read apart from there extensions.

Comment: `fgets` can read CSVs so maybe it's not CSV at all?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot It can .... no doubt in that. But my program is to read line by line. I have the file size of 9 GB. Hence, I need to read the files line by line. But, the file which is CSV, it is trying to fetch all the content at once, not line by line for process. Hence, it is making a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

Well your files are different. Because of that you will have to take a different approach for each of those. In more general terms this is usually calling adapting and is mostly provided using the [Adapter design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Should you use the adapter design pattern you would have a code inspecting the extension of a file to be opened and a `switch` with either `txt` or `csv`. Based on the value you would retrieve a `TxtParser` or a `CsvParser` respectively.

However, before diving deep into this territory you might want to have a look at the files first. I cannot say this for sure without seeing the structures but you can. If the contents of both the text and csv files are the same then a very simple approach is to change the extension to either txt or a csv for all files and then process them using same logic, knowing files with the same extension will now be processed in the same manner.

But from what I understood the file structures actually differ. So to keep your code concise the adapter pattern, having two separate classes/functions for parsing and another one on top of that for choosing the right parsing function (this top function would actually be a form of a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) and running it.

Either way, I very much doubt so there is a solution for the problem you are facing as a file structure is mostly your and your own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so problem is when CSV file has too long string line. Based on this restriction I suggest you to use example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) Here is an example:

```
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
        // do your operation for searching here
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```